# IBaNTsJTtStPMP! #2

Tags: grid-deduction, masyu

<sub>*IBaNTsJTtStPMP means "[I'm Bad at Naming Things, so Just Try to Solve this Patterned Masyu Puzzle!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85853/im-bad-at-naming-things-so-just-try-to-solve-this-patterned-masyu-puzzle)".*</sub>

---

[image]

> **The original [Masyu rules](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) apply.**
>
> 1. Make a single loop with lines passing through the centers of cells, horizontally or vertically. The loop never crosses itself, branches off, or goes through the same cell twice.
> 2. Lines must pass through all cells with black and white circles.
> 3. Lines passing through white circles must pass straight through its cell, and make a right-angled turn in at least one of the cells next to the white circle.
> 4. Lines passing through black circles must make a right-angled turn in its cell, then it must go straight through the next cell (till the middle of the second cell) on both sides.

*For an online player, try **[here](https://puzz.link/p?mashu/13/13/0093000006k6i0k6i0k6k326k0000003a303a3b0a390a3a00000i2i20)**.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Completed:

> [image: solution]

Interim steps (mostly obvious I think... comment if anything is unclear and needs some explanation):

> [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: why can't the two continuous black spots on the bottom row form a u-shape?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton - because lines have to turn on black circles and then "must go straight through the next cell", which would be impossible if it had to turn immediately again on the black circle.

Comment: oops... i completely missed this rule... thanks!

Comment: Feels like seeing circuit board :)